# Simple program not giving desired output

Tags: c#

I am starting to learn `c#` and I have a simple program to request two numbers from the user and add them together. When I run my program , I get asked for the first number , I type it in and that's it, the program doesn't go any further. I am running it in `visual studio`

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
using System;

namespace Coding
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int number1;
            int number2;
            int result;


            Console.WriteLine("Enter first  number to be calculated");
            number1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


            Console.WriteLine("Enter second  number to be calculated");
            number2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            result = number1 + number2;
            Console.WriteLine("The Total is" + " " + result);
        }
    }
}
```

result screenshot
[image]

Comment: You need to press enter after entering the number, it's reading a line

Comment: Most likely the program ends and shows the results properly. You just don't get to see it. Try adding `Console.ReadKey();` at the end.

Comment: Side note: add `Console.ReadLine()` (or `Console.ReadKey()`) after the last `Console.WriteLine` in order to *pause execution* before exit so that you can look at the output.

Comment: @BartłomiejPopielarz first thought, but there is a second `ReadLine()` and OP said it stops/hangs/crashes at/after the first one

Comment: @RenéVogt That's not what they say.  It sounds like they're expecting to press a number and immediately be asked for the second number, without having to press enter.  Once they resolve that issue (if that is the issue) then Bart's comment *needs* to be taken into consideration or the next question will be *"why does my application close without showing the result?"*

Comment: I get asked for first number, i type it in and press enter and it shows the number on the screen and the program doesnt go any further. I dont get asked for the second one

Comment: Can't reproduce, which number exactly do you enter? How does "program doesnt go any further" looks like? Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: Debug the input coming from Console.Readline() there might be a space

Comment: @AndréSanson That still would not explain described behavior.

Comment: i added screenshot

Comment: Oh, so you are **not** in Visual Studio but in Visual Studio **Code** ...

Comment: Never seen such console. Mac? Net .Core?

Comment: @Sinatr that's VS Code Editor with .Net Core

Comment: .net sdk. Where should i run it from so ? I am doing a pluralsight training course and the trainer said to run it this way

Comment: If you would create Console App (.Net Framework) using Visual Studio 2017 (or other version) it would work as it was to me. No experience with VS Code. [edit] question tags and wait until someone who has helps.

Comment: As far as we can tell the code you posted is proper and should run just fine, it is likely an issue with the commandline that you are using. If possible try running the built executable file without visual studio.

Comment: there is no .exe, downloading visual studio now and will try run it again

Comment: ok sorted. in studio code you need to type dotnet restore and then dotnet run and it works fine, thanks everyone